# Send commands to the terminal(Ubuntu) from ipython notebook

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-12.04

Currently I'm looking to send the following commands to the terminal.

```
cd ~/path/folder
./a-opt -i a.i
```

They HAVE to go to the terminal because I've modified my bashrc file to source certain program dependencies. Basically I'm running an executable `a-opt` with the options `-i a.i`

I've searched around the internet a bit on "running executables in terminal from ipython" and mostly what I get is how to create an executable from my python script. I don't want to do this. I want to use my script to run a string of executables. I've looked into

```
import os
```

but that does not seem to solve my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but why was this voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this question by doing the following

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir('path')
subprocess.call('command',shell=True)
```

This does access the .bashrc file as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the python problem:

I think what you want is the commands lib:
[Python Documentation Page[1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html)

```
from commands import getoutput as cmd
```

then you can run

```
cmd("ls;ps;touch myfile")
```

And for what I've tested here, this module does NOT load the .bashrc.